# Not able to find last declined flag

Tags: discussion, flags, declined-flags

While I was reviewing I see below warning,

```
Your last flag was declined - please review it before flagging this post!
```

But when I see flagged post history I am not able to find out which was exactly declined, my last flag was before 2 days, and it is being displayed as helpful.

My declined flag is of 21 February.

Please help to understand this.

[image]

Comment: I had the same issue. I think that sentence should read: *One of your last flags was declined...*

Comment: @rene But My last declined flag is way beyond this month, there are few other flags after that too. So not getting exactly for which flag it is talking about, so that I would be careful in the near future before flagging anything. Thanks for the support.

Comment: Sure, [here you are](http://stackoverflow.com/users/flag-summary/696134) seems only accessible if you are logged in.

Comment: Added screenshot.