# Can we make new flag responses more visible?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, design, flag-history, filtering

When looking at my flag-responses page, it's not always easy to tell what's new.  Sometimes flags take a while to resolve, so I might have one farther down the page that only now got resolved.  Moderators have always been able to leave messages for declined flags and now can leave them for helpful flags too.  If the moderators took the time to write them, we should try to read them.  But right now all I can do is scan the page and see if anything new jumps out at me.

For other types of responses (comments, edits, reputation changes, even changes in favorites), the new information is highlighted through styling (background color).  Could we do something like that for the flags page too?  Or provide some other way for users to see their newly-handled flags?

Comment: Perhaps changing the sort order to when the flag was handled, not when it was cast? That would always bring the newest responses to the front, and make it a lot easier to see what [the new declined flag warning is referring to](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/226294/not-able-to-find-last-declined-flag).

Comment: @BradLarson that would work too.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Allow recovery from flag hellban](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173878/allow-recovery-from-flag-hellban)

Comment: @user2284570: There is no flag hellban anymore. I am not sure how that post is answering this one.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/172262/162102

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As of today, thanks to Oded, filtering the flag history is available. The sidebar on on the history page now has **MOAR** links which can be used to easily see declined, disputed, helpful, etc outcomes of your flags.

Should you be unlucky and are flag banned, then you will be prompted with an easy way to see your previous [7 days of declined flags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/175405/164200).

These changes were made to make the long flag history page a bit easier to maneuver.