# Overview on my recent flagging activity?

Tags: discussion, status-declined, flags, flag-history

So I can always get this:

[image]

Problem is that I cannot see how well I did yesterday, for example, by raising 65 flags, because the above shows all history. Is there any way to see a breakdown on those 65 flags only? If not, would it be difficult to add? I was thinking something like:

```
719 (+65) moderator attention flags
 18 (-47) waiting for review
514 (+ X) deemed helpful
....
```

Where the number in brackets is a change during last 24hrs - can be a configurable option, if user prefers to see 48hrs for some reason, why not. I just think it makes sense to make 24hrs the default, because new flags are granted daily.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/226361/162102

Answer (score 12):

Given that a user's flagging performance is now evaluated based on flags handled recently, this feature, or something similar, is absolutely necessary.

If a user has enough flags declined in the last 7 days, they will begin to receive a warning message to review their recent flags before proceeding.  This is designed to make the user check out their recent flags to see why they were declined, and think twice before continuing with the flag if they have a history of using flags improperly.

And if they continue to receive declined flags, they will be temporarily banned from flagging.  When this happens, the users are again encouraged to review their recent flags to understand why they were banned.

**This a huge problem when you can't find your recently handled flags**.  A user's flag history is listed chronologically based on when they flagged and not when the flag was handled, so it can be quite easy for the recently handled flags causing the ban to be buried in the history and intermingled with unhandled flags (which don't count towards the ban) and flags handled more than 7 days ago (and thus do not factor into the ban).

**TL;DR;**

If we are going to encourage users to review their flagging performance to stave off a flag ban or learn from a ban, we need to provide a mechanism for them to be able to find the flags responsible for the ban, so a mechanism to filter your flags to find the recently handled flag is needed.

Comment: +1. On the flag summary page, we could have a filter similar to how close votes work, where you can select different flag results (active, helpful, disputed, declined). You would generally be interested in declined flags, so one of the workflows is to leave only that one checked. This addition could work complimentary to "recent counts" feature, to help get more organized with flags.

Answer (score 5):

Something similar to this was implemented last week. When you browse your flagging history, you are now able to filter the flags by how it was processed.  You can filter the declined, disputed, even helpful flags and your history will be presented in the order of the date it was processed.

If you are flag banned, then you will be automatically presented with the flags that were declined in the past 7 days (or those flags that triggered the ban).

However, the filtering by further dates Today, Yesterday, This month was deemed too expensive and too cumbersome to implement for the time-being so I'm going to [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) this request.

Comment: Yes, something like that, but it's missing date range selection, i.e. "Flags from - Today, Yesterday, This week, This month, All time etc."

Comment: @Neolisk We looked at adding date filtering but it was too expensive and started to get too complicated to include that many options.

Comment: Expensive, but most useful, this is what my original request was all about. :)

Comment: @Neolisk Then I'll just change this to status-declined because it's too expensive to filter by so many dates.

Comment: @Neolisk since the date is there, userscript should be quite simple to write. You can try asking (nicely :)) in the [Tavern](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/89/tavern-on-the-meta) (chat room) if someone can write such a script.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: Results are fetched by page, they are not shown all at once. Do you suggest to keep parsing new pages inside script until you get to your selected cut-off date? A hassle. Besides, I'm not as active with flags as I used to be.

Comment: @Neolisk true, but sorted by the date, descending. In case of many flags in one day yes it's possible to fetch other pages using AJAX. Bit more complicated, but still possible.