# Make reviewing declined flags less painful

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, flag-history

Today, in my flag dialog box, I got the dreaded message

> Attention: some of your recent flags have been declined - please
>   review them before flagging this post!

I went to the link and I got sent to my flag summary page.

I have 300+ total flags, 7 declined, 13 disputed. I'm sure this is meager compared to a lot of other users. But as it is, it's already tedious to go through the 7 pages of flags at 50 per page just to look for any declined flag.

I suggest that we have a way to sort or filter the flags by status by making the numbers
in flagging history links to a filter/sorting query.

[image: Sort or filter by flag status]

This way, users can actually review declined flags without having to go through pages and pages of all their other flags.

The two important ones are declined and disputed, but it is probably trivial to implement the same functionality across the other flag statuses.

---

I have slightly changed the focus of the question to differentiate it more from [Can we make new flag responses more visible?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/226361/can-we-make-new-flag-responses-more-visible)

The focus of the two questions are different. This one focuses on the message received from having recent declined flags and suggests a better way to access a user's declined flags. The other question focuses on **when** a user flag has been acted upon and a better way to see them.

Comment: Related: [Overview on my recent flagging activity?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/226486/overview-on-my-recent-flagging-activity)

Comment: `ctrl+f`; "declined"; "disputed"

Comment: @Emracool and do that in all pages because you do not know which ones are most recently declined/disputed?

Comment: @rikitikitik - Not having any answer on original question doesn't qualify the duplicate one to remain open.

Comment: I’d really like to be able to sort my flags by activity.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Effective immediately, you will now be able to filter your declined flags by using links in the sidebar stats. By clicking on declined, your flag history will show only those flags.