# Show declined flags in inbox

Tags: feature-request, flags, global-inbox, declined-flags

I propose that moderator flags which are declined should show up in the global inbox, as a way to more clearly and reliably educate the user on why their flags are declined, thus improving the quality of future flags.

[image: visual aid!]

This would not be displayed for helpful/disputed flags, as it would quickly become noise for active users.

While the recent warnings ([Allow recovery from flag hellban](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173878/allow-recovery-from-flag-hellban/175405#175405)) likely help, good users can also benefit from this feedback, even if they wouldn't ever reach the level of seeing the quality warnings.

From the linked Shog9 post:

> For this to be effective, it must include feedback on how well you're flagging - closing that feedback loop should help our more prolific flaggers to become better at flagging

This feature aims to further improve that feedback, and shrink the feedback loop for *everyone*, not just the poor flaggers.

Comment: This seems like it might be a little too in-your-face and could get a little noisy. Flags get declined all the time, and they're not urgent matters usually. Instead, I think better sorting of flags by response time: [Can we make new flag responses more visible?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/226361/can-we-make-new-flag-responses-more-visible) would expose this, as could a listing of recently declined flags in the warning you get when trying to flag. You'd still be presented with this information, but only right when you'd need it (as you were about to flag again).

Comment: That's a good point about urgency, but it seems a middle ground might be in order, as currently there's zero feedback. I do particularly like your suggestion made on the linked page for sorting by handled date. Plus an unread color-coding like used in other user pages

Comment: [Send custom flag responses to messages inbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/239738/266359) ....sorry, didn't see your question earlier. In short, I agree that putting flag responses in the inbox would be useful, but I think *all* of them would be a bit much. My suggestion is to put only the custom responses into the inbox....perhaps as a sort of "middle ground"