# Sending a notification when a flag is reviewed

Tags: feature-request, flags, notifications

There should be a notification when a moderator reviews or looks at a post which you've flagged.

The notification could show the status (helpful, declined, disputed, or something else) of your flag.

**Edit**

The reason for doing this is so that you would be able to see *when* a post which you have flagged has received moderator attention, at which point you could go back to the post. This would be good, for instance, if:

- you flagged a post for migration to another site; after migration occurs, you could answer the question, since [the FAQ suggests](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10250/201907) that only unanswered questions should get migrated
- you flagged a post for removal of spam or otherwise nonconstructive content, and the content removal has to be carried out in batches

Comment: @Shog this is clearly not a duplicate. The other one is only for flags declined with a custom message, this one here is for getting a notification always, for any status of the flag, so that the user won't have to check the flag history all the time.

Comment: Anyway, unless this will be an opt-in feature, it means tons of noise for users who flag a lot. Some users cast 100 flags every day, so 100 inbox notifications will be lots of noise for them

Comment: I wouldn't mind being notified about _declined_ flags, as they're a) rare and b) I might learn something by re-examining the flagged post.  But notifying me that one of the 10 non-answers I flagged from the Late Answers queue was deleted would be very annoying, especially as Stack notifications make my phone ding.

Answer (score 5):

The *vast* majority of flags don't need further attention from the flagger. I had suggested [showing declined flags in the inbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228267/show-declined-flags-in-inbox), but it seems you want *all* of them. Eek!

What makes more sense would probably be to star ("favorite", but I dislike the term in this case) the question, so it shows up on your profile page once the flag has triggered a change. That way you can do this just for the flags you *want* to follow up on, without getting inundated with noise for the ones you don't.

Answer (score 4):

<strike>You haven't given any reason *why* this should happen.</strike>

The results of your flags are already available in your profile, just click on the number next to the *helpful flags* caption, or use the URL

```
https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/flag-summary/[your user ID number]
```

For you (and only you) this would [take you here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/flag-summary/201907).

**Edit:**
To answer your specific points:

> you flagged a post for migration to another site...

Answers get migrated with the question. The FAQ is suggesting a best practice, this doesn't mean you can't answer before migrating.

> you flagged a post for removal of spam or otherwise nonconstructive content, and the content removal has to be carried out in batches

Huh? To me this makes no sense. When a moderator deletes something it's done instantly, by definition a single (flagged) item cannot be deleted "in batches".

Comment: See my edit to the post, which gives some reasons why this should happen.

Comment: @APerson Answer updated...

Answer (score 1):

Your suggestion doesn't scale well. I've raised over 5000 flags on Stack Overflow; my inbox would be useless to me if it contained such information. Other users have raised [even more flags than that](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280546/can-a-machine-be-taught-to-flag-comments-automatically).

Additionally if I flag a comment, a question or an answer and it's deleted by a moderator because I flagged it, what action can I then take? Since the answer is that there's nothing for me to do in that case it's just noise. If I needed something else to happen other than post deletion, e.g., check all the user's posts because they all have the same issue I'm flagging, I'd raise a custom flag and say so.

If the moderators have something special to say about my flagging they have the ability to tell me and for one, perhaps two of my flags they did so. That's useful information and already happens.