# At flag history page add a link to filter by retracted ("self-removed") flags

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, flag-history, filtering, retracted-flags

Since [October 2015](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/268372/165773) flag history page provides filters for various flag outcomes:

> <sup>links which can be used to easily see declined, disputed, helpful, etc outcomes of your flags...</sup>
>
> <sup>These changes were made to make the long flag history page a bit easier to maneuver.</sup>

In [July 2016](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/281010/165773) (network wide in August) it became possible to cancel (retract) flags. This added a new kind of outcome to the flag history - in unfiltered page such flags are marked as "self-removed".

Currently there is no way to filter flag history page by cancelled flags outcome:
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DuEo7.png]

Suggest to add a link allowing to filter flag history by cancelled flags just like it is done for other kind outcomes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This has been done in the latest build.  You'll see a new filter category called **retracted** which will filter any of the flags you self-removed.  Thanks to [Michael Stum](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/91/michael-stum) for getting this out so quickly!

> [image: New Flag History]

Comment: fix confirmed: I see retracted category in my flag summary page and link works as expected, referring to the list of the flags I retracted

Answer (score 4):

I agree, there should be a link.

Not so much because it's important to be able to filter out only self-removed flags, but because currently **the flag counts don't add up**. From your screenshot:

> 14,976 post flags
>
> ---
>
> 1 waiting for review
>   14,570 helpful
>   299 declined
>   105 disputed

But 1+14,570+299+105 isn't 14,976; it's 14,975. This discrepancy between the whole and the sum of its apparent parts will drive pedants like myself absolutely wild!